# Using custom fields in a filter hook

Tags: custom-field, filters, hooks

I'd like to add some code from a single post theme file into a filter but I'm not sure how to do it because it includes the get_post_meta() function. I've searched but can't seem to figure it out.

Code in `single-post.php` theme file:

```
$apoth_original_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'original_blog_title', true);
$apoth_original_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'original_url', true);
?>
<a id="apoth_readmore" class="w-btn style_solid size_medium color_primary icon_none" href="<?php echo $apoth_original_url?>"><span class="w-btn-label">Read More at <em><?php echo $apoth_original_title ?></em></span></a>
<?php
```

Attempted filter in `functions.php`:

```
function apoth_readmore_link( $content ) {
if( is_single() ) {

    $content .= '<a href="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'original_url', true) . '"> Read More</a>' ;
}
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'apoth_readmore_link' )
```

I get that this isn't working because `get_post_meta()` doesn't echo the custom field data, but I don't know how to assign that to a variable and then echo it in the context of a filter function. Or maybe there is some other way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: So you would like to modify `original_blog_title` and `original_url` from `functions.php` then render the link with filtered content?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to reference the [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) that created the page.

> - if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
> - if you're on a page, it will return the page object
> - if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
> - if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
> - if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object
> - etc.

```
function apoth_readmore_link( $content ) {

    $post = get_queried_object();

    if ( get_class($post)==='WP_Post' ) {

        $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'original_url', true);

        $content .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">Read More</a>', $url, $url );
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'apoth_readmore_link' );
```

Comment: Any luck with this?