# Add custom fields to post programmatically

Tags: posts, customization, custom-field

I want to create some custom fields that will be able to show to a default wordpress post. I don't want to use the ACF plugin.
Is there anyway to do it programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom fields included in wordpress

Add a new post and do the following steps:

**1. Go to the Options page**

[image: select options page]

**2. Select "custom fields" and hit the reload button**

[image: select the custom field option and reload]

**3. you now have a custom field in your post edit page at the bottom.**

[image: custom field]

now you can use this custom field in your theme inside the `post-loop`

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the post(); ?>

    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You have to replace 'featured' with the name of your custom field.

Once you created a custom field, you can use it in your others post as well.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Should I add this code inside my functions.php file?

Comment: have a look at the following post, I think this should help you
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246324/using-custom-fields-in-a-filter-hook

Answer (score 0):

This article walks you through creating a very basic, lightweight plugin to add your own meta fields. I'm sure it could be adapted to be used as a standalone function rather than a plugin.

https://metabox.io/how-to-create-custom-meta-boxes-custom-fields-in-wordpress/

Essentially you add your fields using `add_meta_box()` and setting the post type to `post` or whatever CPT you like. Update the fields using `update_post_meta()`. Then display wherever you like using `get_post_meta()`.

[add_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

[update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

[get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: Answers need to be self contained, you can link offsite for supporting material e.g. further reading, but the link can't be the answer itself

Comment: Noted, thank you.